# Добавление новых дочерних элементов с помощью XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Например, есть у меня обычная форма с двумя `textbox` и одним `button`. По задумке, после ввода какого-либо текста и нажатия на кнопку, в `XML` файл должны добавиться эти значения. С формированием тела xml с помощью xml я разобрался без проблем. MSDN на этот счёт имеет исчерпывающую справку:

```
XElement xmlTree1 = new XElement("Root",
    new XElement("Child1", 1),
    new XElement("Child2", 2),
    new XElement("Child3", 3),
    new XElement("Child4", 4),
    new XElement("Child5", 5),
    new XElement("Child6", 6)
);
```

Но метод `AddAfterSelf` из того же справочника я понять не могу. Как сделать так, что-бы после ввода каких либо значений, они добавлялись в конец документа?
Пусть это даже не textbox, а значение, взятое из `Console.Readline()`;

Дополнение:

Сообщество меня заминусовало, но в целом справедливо. Поскольку на момент ответа самому себе, я не до конца понимал, как это работает :)
Когда я задал вопрос, я не остановился на поисках ответа и нашёл его.

Изначальная цель была добавить новый дочерний элемент в корень Root. Я пологал, что это делается через метод `AddAfterSelf`, но где-то в подсознании я понимал, что это наверное не правильно (что очевидно, ведь не работает так, как я хочу). Дальше я пытался добавить элемент простым добавлением `new XElement("Child1", Textbox.text),`но и это не помогало. Файл по итогу всё равно не менялся. Но после настойчивого перечитывания MSDN и примеров других программистов, я понял свою ошибку.
То есть, я не выполнял несколько очевидных моментов, которые негласно существуют и ясны как 2х2 тем, кто имеет больше опыта.
Фактически, сперва я должен был загрузить файл, с которым собираюсь работать: `var EventLibrary = XElement.Load("EventFile.xml");`
После этого, мне нужно было вызывать метод `XContainer. Add` с указанием имени корня, что бы в дальшейшем XContainer знал, что есть Root, а что есть дочерний элемент. Ну, а затем сохранять результат работы в файл.
После этого, мои XML документ начал наполняться так, как я и хотел.

Comment: Я конечно извиняюсь, но по данному Вам ответу и Вашему решению, открыть и сохранить файл, я так и не понял в чем была проблема и причем здесь AddAfterSelf

Comment: Добавил пояснение своего ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я вышел из ситуации следующим путём:

- Открываю документ с помощью XElement.load(file);
- Затем, делаю ADD(Описываю тело документа)
- Сохраняю документ с помощью XElement.save(file);

Answer (score 1):

Например, так:

```
int n = xmlTree1.Elements().Count() + 1;
string text = "Console input or textbox text or whatever";
xmlTree1.Add(new XElement("Child" + n, text));
```